# Meteor Performance Issue when sorting client side

Tags: sorting, meteor, client-side, iron-router

I am quite new on Meteor (3 weeks)
I have a precise issue when I need to load data from a collection.
The collection contains 2800 objects (small posts)

On client side, I limit at the 25 first posts

But If I want to sort (on createdAt which is a Date field), I try this 2 solutions:

- sort on client side:
  It was a big mistake as Chrome is blocked => performance issue

  - sort on server side:
    It's better because I don't have performance issue anymore but datas are not reactive anymore: I have a form on the same page and when I add a new post, it doesn't appear in the list (It appears if refresh manually)

So I'm looking for a solution to improve performance when sorting on client side or another one to solve reactivity whithout sorting

I'm using iron-router

I already tried to subscribe at different place without success.

I read a lot about meteor here without finding something that could help me

Many thanks for your help

Comment: On publish function send them sorted and with limit, you can also have a param on that to control the limit, skip.

Comment: Thank you Marius, what I did as a short term solution is near your solution: I put a limit param when I subscribe, and I publish with that limit so that the sorted client side is not a problem, but it limits my 'see more' link to increase the limit

Comment: And If I don't sort on client side, datas aren't reactive anymore